# Creating <td> directive with Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers-3

I am trying to make an Angular 1.5 directive work within an `ng-repeat` for a `table`.  A few things I need this to do (and please, if I am going at this the completely wrong way, let me know):

1) Update the html whenever new results are provided.  Most importantly, the link function gets called once, with an empty result, and never called again.  So, my table is blank.  Always.
2) Inside the 'template' of the directive, I reference the controller's name and a method which is type coupling.  Is the 'right' way to do this?

Here's my code snippets...

**module-a.view.html**:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="(ii,result) in moduleACtrl.results">
   <td>This is a normal TD</td>
   <td-result result="{{result}}" ctrlName="moduleACtrl"></td-result>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATED**
**common.td-result.directive.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    /* global angular */// ESLINT
    angular.module('common').directive('tdResult',Directive);

    Directive.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function Directive($compile){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {
                result : '@',     
                ctrlName : '@'  
            },
            template: '<td>{{result.prop1}}</td>\
                        <td>{{result.prop2}}</td>\
                        <td>{{result.prop3}}</td>\
                        <td><div ng-click="ctrlName.doSomething()">Something Goes Here {{ctrlName}}</div></td>'
        };
    }
 })();
```

After reading a number of related questions on StackOverflow, and re-reviewing Angular's Directives documentation, I cannot figure out how to do what I want.

The overall context that got me here is that I have an OpenLayers 3 map, displaying result data from a query.  I have the result data on the map interactively displaying result data when you click on it, like this: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html

The difference though, is that I am using Angular 1.5.  I have a ModuleA with a controller and view that house the map.  I have another ModuleCommon that houses a service that handles creation of the map object and hands it to ModuleA.controller (or any controller who wants the map service).  So, now, I have to create an interface for the map service that can generically handle displaying data to any client who wants to render said data.

Comment: you are inserting inside the directive element so that would be `<td><td></td></td>` which is invalid. To be honest if you have a known number of properties I don't see any benefit to even creating a directive template for this

Comment: also for 2 way binding in scope you need to use `'='` not `'@'` and the watch would be automatic

Comment: So, this was originally just html within an ng-repeat and all was well.  But then I realized I need this snippet of <td>s somewhere else, but not the ng-repeat.  So, I thought, let's make this a directive.  But maybe I should just repeat this code?  Not sure what the best option is right now.

Comment: in most instances would be good approach but table elements are very specific about allowed children

Comment: You could repeat `<tbody>` instead of `<tr>` which might help

Comment: Shoot. OK.  Well, I will continue down the 'repeat code' path for now.  Hurts to violate DRY, but getting it to work is more important right now.

Comment: can you tell us why you need this kind of custom directive ?Clearly sending ctrl name and calling function is not a right way and that doesn't work like that. `ng-repeat` creates its own scope and with directive you are creating an isolate scope over there,I assume you want to reduce the HTML code redundancy but then you want to create a directive which shares controller scope but not isolated scope.

Comment: @Angular_10 I think this is clearly a rabbit-hole I found myself in.  Originally, I saw a repeated <td> pattern, and my first thought was 'directive'.  But as I look further into it, especially with the controller reference, and being inside an ng-repeat, this seems like a bad idea.  However, and I don't know how to use StackOverflow to communicate this, this leads me to the question, what is it I am trying to do and is there a best practice or intelligent approach?  Because right now, this feels completely brute force and all a very bad idea.

Comment: Hmm yea ! If you ever wanted to reduce redundant code and have common template everywhere create a directive which binds to particular controller as in your case but not isolate scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this was all a bad idea and that I need to step way back.  First, the map object should not be responsible for displaying the data.  The map is responsible for handling the 'singleclick' event and getting me a feature.

So, I decided that the controller, which instantiates the map object via the map service, will simply be responsible for creating and sending a callback to the map object so the map object knows what it's client wants on a singleclick.  The getFeature is the map object's responsibility, and what to do with the feature's id is the client's (i.e. controller's) responsibility.

Whew!

Map code:

```
map.on('singleclick',function(event){
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel,function(feature){
        callback(feature.getId());
    });
});
```

Controller Code:

```
...
function mapCallback(someId){
    var elem = angular.element('#info');
    if ( someId === undefined ) {
        elem.slideUp(); // Hide element
    } else {
        for (var data, ii = 0, len = vm.dataList.length; ii < len; ii++) {
            data = vm.dataList[ii];
            if ( someId === data.property ) {
                vm.currentData = data;
                $scope.$apply();
                elem.slideDown(); // Show element
                break;
            } else {
                elem.slideUp(); // Hide element
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

1) The Map is de-coupled from the data pertaining to the feature.

2) The Controller controls what happens when the map selects its data.

3) The HTML stays in the Controller's associated Component's templateUrl where it belongs!